# How to change the font of JLabel without chaning style or size?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, fonts

Setting the font of a `JLabel` goes like:

```
JLabel.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 18));
```

So I have to pass all the 3 variables into to the `Font` constructor to make it work.
I want to change only one of these parameters without affecting/mentioning the others

I want something like :-

```
JLabel.setFontName("Verdana");
```

or

```
JLabel.setFontSize(18);
```

or

```
JLabel.setFontStyle(Font.Bold);
```

**Is there something similar available?**

Comment: Yes.  label.setFont(panel.getFont().deriveFont("Verdana");  The deriveFont method allows you to change the font style or font size individually.  The font size is expressed as a float, rather than an int.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc There are `deriveFont` methods  for changing size & style, but not one for the font family. The programmer needs to create a font with new family name, then derive the font (from settings in the original) for the size and style.

Comment: Actually, my bad. I did not read the question carefully before replying. The *easiest* way to change the font family would be to construct the font using the string of the family name, together with the style (`int`) & size (`float`) of the original font.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson: Thanks for correcting my mistake.  I should have looked before I answered.  I always use the same font for a GUI but different font styles and sizes.